# AWS Lambda Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system

Tags: firebase, aws-lambda, glibc, google-cloud-firestore, grpc

I have problem with AWS Lambda function deployment with Serverless Framework. I use `@google-cloud-firestore` npm package which requires `grpc` package.

Function execution throws error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system\nExpected directory: node-v48-linux-x64-glibc\nFound: [node-v59-darwin-x64-unknown]\nThis problem can often be fixed by running \"npm rebuild\" on the current system\nOriginal error: Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v48-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Found: [node-v48-linux-x64-unknown]",
    "This problem can often be fixed by running \"npm rebuild\" on the current system",
    "Original error: Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v48-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:44:17)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:38:12)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)"
  ]
}
```

So, as I understood, lambda requires grps built with target `node-v48-linux-x64-glibc`

Typing `npm i -S grpc --target=6.4.0 --target_arch=x64 --target_platform=linux` has only changed `node-v59-darwin-x64-unknown` to `node-v48-linux-x64-unknown`.

How can I change `unknown` to `glibc`?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: There may be a better solution, but the obvious one that comes to mind would be to build the module on a machine created using the [Lambda Execution Environment AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Fix](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/6443#issuecomment-355722144)

Basically, you need to specify the target of the grcp library.
Copied from that link:

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  "postinstall": "npm rebuild grpc --target=6.1.0 --target_arch=x64 --target_platform=linux --target_libc=glibc"
  }
}
```

Comment: Was a bit confused about this at first, but realized this was a local install step and not anything that happens on the server. I'm using node 8.10.0 so once I changed it to that version, and `npm install` locally before deploying it worked great. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: I gave this a try, and still no luck. Do I need to make some configs in AWS? Getting the following error: "errorMessage": `/var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node: invalid ELF header`. Have also tried adding the  `--update-binary` flag but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I got something similar to work by including a `--target_libc=glibc`, found in the [documentation for node-pre-gyp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pre-gyp).